# First-person, present-tense novels where the plot arcs on deep change within the protagonist's life from the negative to the positive

Tags: novel, character-development, book-rec

I'm doing research and preparatory writing on a novel and that's going really well.  But I need some perspective on some of the technical issues. I need to dissect a couple of specimens.

What popular books are first-person, present-tense novels where the plot arcs on deep change within the protagonist's life from the negative to the positive? There's a couple of love stories in my novel but it's the personal transformation that's at the core of it, so the conventional love story structure won't work.

Answer (score 1):

- Hunger Games
- Odd Thomas
- The True History of the Kelly Gang
- Vernon God Little